# How to solve 0xc0000005 on windows server 2012

Tags: apache, windows-server-2012-r2, php-5.6

In my server windows server 2012 r2 I Have this problem.

Faulting application name: httpd.exe, version: 2.4.29.0, time stamp: 0x59edc80e
Faulting module name: php5ts.dll, version: 5.6.32.0, time stamp: 0x59f11cfa
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000012e1a
Faulting process id: 0xf4c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d5ab4a06d8a061
Faulting application path: C:\Bitnami\WAMPST~1.32-\apache2\bin\httpd.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Bitnami\WAMPST~1.32-\apache2\bin\php5ts.dll
Report Id: 65c7c47c-173d-11ea-9465-4c72b94efe7f
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: Me too having this issue on and off for months. However not able to find any solid solution for this.

Comment: finally we installed wampserver instead of bitnami because bitnami's php5ts.dll file spits.